# How to search nested lists in Mongo C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I can run it in Robomongo, but I do not know how to do this in C #

```
db.getCollection('package').find({'Items': {$elemMatch: {'Coupons': {$elemMatch:{_id : 33944115}}}}})
```

I try this code, but aways returns null.

```
var filter = Builders<Coupon>.Filter.Eq(coupon => coupon.Id, 33944115);
var filter1 = Builders<Item>.Filter.ElemMatch(item => item.Coupons, filter);
var filter2 = Builders<Package>.Filter.ElemMatch(package => package.Items, filter1);
var result = PackageCollection.Find(filter2).FirstOrDefault();
```

My Class:

```
public class Package
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
}

public class Coupon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the query is correct. It was the connection that was wrong.